# How do I resume inCallScreen automatically?

Tags: android

I want to resume inCallScreen automatically when users switch task in call.

I wrote below codes in service and execute periodically, but it affected nothing.

```
ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) appContext.getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);

List<RunningTaskInfo> taskList = am.getRunningTasks(10);
for (RunningTaskInfo info : taskList) {
    String packageName = info.topActivity.getPackageName();
    if (packageName.equals("com.android.phone")) {
        am.moveTaskToFront(info.id, 0);
        break;
    }
}
```

Of course I declared "`GET_TASKS`" and "`REORDER_TASKS`" permissions in `AndroidManifest.xml`.
Above code runs normally when "com.android.phone" is replaced with the other package names.

How do I automatically resume inCallScreen?
Are there any other ways to do that I want?